# WordPress: Front End wp_editor Missing Buttons

Tags: wordpress, button, plugins, editor

I installed a [third-party plugin](http://www.diversesolutions.com/idx/idx-plugin-for-wordpress) which adds a few buttons to WordPress' WYSIWYG editor, but these buttons are only showing up on the back-end (edit posts/pages) and not on my front-end instances.

I noticed that the [wp_editor](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function has an argument for loading TinyMCE. Is there a way to get this third-party plugin to load on the front-end similarly, so that I can take advantage of the same editor buttons that it adds to the back-end?

Comment: Including this third-party plugin that adds buttons.

Comment: It looks like the plugin is behind a paywall!

Comment: I guess, he means to say that for anyone who can help you in this have to purchase the plugin first.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the plugin, but you could try and search the plugin code for the add_filter that adds the buttons to the editor, then add the function call it uses to wherever you are loading your front-end editor.